# WingIDE Debug Message:No debug process

Tags: debugging, macos, x11, wing-ide

After reading all stack commentary and trial running several other Python IDEs I'd like to use WingIDE for Python but getting stuck on debug process. I want to:

1) test a script of def function module in editor that prompts user for response (ie raw_input('Enter your Name')
2) enter the corresponding input in the Python shell when prompted
3) see the results of function in Python Shell

However this is the error message I receive in WingIDE Messages box:
Debugger: Listening for back-connection
Debugger: Connected to debug process
Debugger: Debug process running: pid=27554 [0 modules loaded]
Debugger: No debug process/not listening for connections

Message in WingIDE OS Commands:
Process Failed to Start

Project PythonPath is set to:
 /Users/myname/Python-2.4.6

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The OS Commands tool doesn't run things in the debugger, but just in a separate process space.  Use Debug/Continue in the Debug menu and then you will see the prompt from raw_input() in the Debug I/O tool and you can enter your input there.  If you want to work in the Python Shell instead, use Evaluate File in Python Shell in the Source menu.  You may want to run through the tutorial in the Help menu.